# Issues with viewing Oracle tables on local host and IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, iis, odbc

I am receiving two errors, which depend on what references I am using, but I think they are both relatively similar issues.

The first error with this reference:

```
Using System.Data.OracleClient;
```

Which causes an error of:

```
Attempt to load Oracle client libraries threw BadImageFormatException.  This problem will occur when running in 64 bit mode with the 32 bit Oracle client components installed.
```

I understand that this reference is depreciated, so I used this Oracle reference:

```
Using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;
```

But this give me an error of:

```
The type initializer for 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection' threw an exception
```

Both of these references work with my Oracle stored procedure on local host, but they throw these errors when I run the page in IIS. On my server I have the Oracle 64-bit client installed, but on my actual computer I have the 32-bit client installed.

My major question is: Why would the Oracle database connect to the server on local host, and execute my stored procedure perfectly even though I have a 32-bit client installed on my machine and a 64-bit client on my server?

I have enabled 32-bit applications on my application pool in IIS, and that did not correct the issue. I have also tried copying the 64-bit Oracle .dll's into my project, but this also did not work.

Would installing the 64-bit client on my machine, and then rebuilding the project with the proper oracle .dll's solve the problem? Will I also need to regenerate another connection string?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using Oracle Managed Data Access (Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll)?  That assembly is MSIL so may help you avoid any 32-bit/64-bit architecture mismatch errors.

Comment: I commented earlier asking if I still needed Oracle.DataAccess.Client, but I realized that you can use Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client. I will check tomorrow to see if this solves the problem. Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As posted by [Luke Woodward](https://stackoverflow.com/users/48503/luke-woodward), by changing Oracle.DataAccess.Client to Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client, the code runs like a charm. Thanks Luke!